Why is this code with ClosedXML not working: BC32023 Expression is of type 'IXLRow', which is not a collection type
I have tried my own brain and severail AI tools but somehow this code with ClosedXML generates an error:
BC32023 Expression is of type 'IXLRow', which is not a collection type.
For Each cell As IXLCell In firstRow
The goal i have with the code was to place a table from an Excel worksheet into a datatable for some data analyses. Although this is not the final situation i wanted to see if i could copy the data into a datagrid. But the above error is hard to bypass. Any ideas why this wont work?

`Public Shared Function ImportExceltoDataTable(filePath As String)
Dim wb As XLWorkbook = New XLWorkbook(filePath)
Try
Using wb
Form1.ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0
Dim wsByName As IXLWorksheet = wb.Worksheet("ADRES") ' Access worksheet by name
            Dim dtADRES As New System.Data.DataTable

            'Add Columns from the first row of the worksheet
            Dim firstRow As IXLRow = wsByName.Rows(1)
            **For Each cell As IXLCell In firstRow**
                If firstRow.CellsUsed().Count > 0 Then
                    dtADRES.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString())
                End If
            Next

            ' Add data from the remaining rows to the DataTable
            For Each row As IXLRow In wsByName.RowsUsed().Skip(1)
                Dim dataRow As DataRow = dtADRES.NewRow()
                For i As Integer = 0 To dtADRES.Columns.Count - 1
                    dataRow(i) = row.Cell(i + 1).Value
                Next
                dtADRES.Rows.Add(dataRow)
            Next

            ' Use the DataTable as needed
            Console.WriteLine("DataTable contains {0} rows and {1} columns.", dtADRES.Rows.Count, dtADRES.Columns.Count)
            For Each row As DataRow In dtADRES.Rows
                Console.WriteLine("{0}")
            Next

            wb.Dispose()



            Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dtADRES
            Form1.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()

        End Using
        Form1.ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 100
        Form1.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Klaar, de spreadsheet is ingelezen!"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function`

I tried several code samples but in all there were some errors related to the same error. I tried extensivly ChatGPT and Gemini but without success.I made sure that the header of the worksheet contained valid cell values to act as column headers.

As the error message indicates, firstRow is not a collection type and you can't enumerate over it.
Rather enumerate over firstRow.Cells() or firstRow.CellsUsed() depending on your requirements. The former will enumerate over all cells in the row (even if they're empty) and the latter will enumerate only over cells that have content or styles or formulas.

Thanks for your reaction.
Meanwhile solved it with this code what works


          'Loop through the Worksheet rows
                Dim firstRowKoppelingen As Boolean = True
                For Each row As IXLRow In wsKoppelingen.Rows
                    'Use the first row to add columns to DataTable
                    If firstRowKoppelingen Then
                        For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells
                            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()) Then
                                GlobalClass.dtKOPPELINGEN.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString())
                            Else
                                Exit For 'Exit inner loop if cell is empty
                            End If
                        Next
                        firstRowKoppelingen = False
                    Else
                        Dim i As Integer = 0
                        Dim toInsert As DataRow = GlobalClass.dtKOPPELINGEN.NewRow()
                        For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells(1, GlobalClass.dtKOPPELINGEN.Columns.Count)
                            Try
                                toInsert(i) = cell.Value.ToString()
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                'Handle cell value conversion errors (optional)
                            End Try
                            i += 1
                        Next
                        GlobalClass.dtKOPPELINGEN.Rows.Add(toInsert)
                    End If
                Next

